# Flex Advanced Datagrid - access value of itemrenderer of one column from other column

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, advanceddatagrid

I have a AdvancedDatagrid with two columns lets say.
First column has item renderer as DropdownList.

Now, on change of DropdownList, I want to update label in second column, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access flex objects with their IDs just like here. Hope this helps

```
 <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="FirstColumn" id="yourFirstColumnId" dataField="FirstColumnDataProvider" change="functionName">

      <fx:Script>
          <![CDATA[


        public function functionName():void
        {
        yourSecondColumnId.headerText= "".
        }
               ]]>

         </fx:Script> 
        </mx:DataGridColumn>

 <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="SecondColumn" id="yourSecondColumnid" >
```

Comment: Umar, thanks for quick response but this is not what I am looking for, . Question here is that I want to be able to set labels in particular AdvancedDatagridColumn depending on another Column's--> itemrenderer's(here, it is a dropdown list) selected Item value. How from itemrenderer's data, I can set data in other column.

Comment: Datagrid column has a property change it dispatches an event which can call a function.